# Regex to recognise unicode special characters

Tags: php, regex

I currently have this Regex

`^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})`

Which requires 1 Capital, Numeric and Special Character whilst being of 8 length.

However, when using Unicode characters such as [” or ™] I'd like to be able to recognize them without declaring them within the `(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])` section. Can someone help me out with the syntax for auto detection of Unicode special characters?

In addition, i wanted to add support for foreign characters using `\p{L} instead of a-z` however i couldn't figure this out for capitals.

Working Example: `Password1!`

Not working Example: `Password1”`

KR, Jordan

Comment: Can you provide sample string?

Comment: Try `'~^(?=\P{Ll}*\p{Ll})(?=\P{Lu}*\p{Lu})(?=\D*\d)(?=[^\p{P}\p{S}]*[\p{P}\p{S}]).{8,}~u'`

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh..... Example provided.

Comment: Also check this: https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html